# What is the equivalent of this Python based comparison solution for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

I have built this function some time ago, in Python and I now have to implement a similar solution in Javascript. I am new to Javascript so I am having a bit of a hard time solving this problem.

This is my Python code:

```py
import operator

# Operator constants
operators = [operator.eq, operator.lt, operator.gt]
labels = ["=", "<", ">"]

def get_comparison_operator(a, b):
        """
        A function that returns an operator string based on the relation between
        the supplied two numbers.
        """
        for op, label in zip(operators, labels):
            if op(b, a):
                return label
        return '?'

get_comparison_operator(2,6) # returns '<'
```

This uses a python module called `operator`. Was not sure if there is a euqilevant js package.

Comment: `I am having a bit of a hard time solving this problem` Please post the Javascript code you've tried that isn't working, so we can see what's going wrong and try to debug it.

Comment: Ok. let me clean it up a bit. Obviously, the python version relies on a specific module. So attempting to replicate the module behavior in javascript.

Comment: not sure why you can't just define function ie. function comp(l, r) {
  return (l < r) ? "<" : ((l === r) ? "=" : ">")
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript there is no such module `operator` as like in Python, but we can create in object for that, and implement the specific methods for it. 
Also, vanilla Javascript does not have `zip` function, but we do not need it since we will iterate through the object:

```
const operators = {
    "=": (a, b) => a === b,
    "<": (a, b) => a < b,
    ">": (a, b) => a > b
 }

 const getComparisionOperator = (a, b) => {
     for (const operator in operators) {
         if (operators[operator](a, b)) {
             return operator;
         }
     }
     return "?";
 }

 console.log(getComparisionOperator(4, 5));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both solutions work but for the sake of consistency, I will accept this one as this answer is better formatted and has some contextual information. I really appreciate your time and I am grateful for both of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
const comparators = {
    'EQ': (a, b) => (a == b),
    'LT': (a, b) => (a < b),
    'GT': (a, b) => (a > b)
}

const compare = (a, b) => {
    for (let key of Object.keys(comparators)) {
        fn = comparators[key]
        if (fn(a, b)) {
            return key
        }
    }
    return null
}
```